# How to obtain local time slope from GAM model

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a model where I try to model the linear trend in my response over time
The trend may vary by elevation and location

As far as I understood the `mgcv` package in R, a GAM model would look like:

```r
Y ~ Year + elevation + Year:elevation +s(lat, lon, bs="gp") + 
     ti(lat, lon, Year, d=c(2, 1), bs=c("gp", "tp"))
```

I have a gaussian error and identity link.

I saw `ti()` is a tensor product interaction, but it is a non-linear interaction. I want a non-linear interaction for location but not for year, here I want just a slope

How can I estimate a slope for each location?

In linear regression considering only year and elevation I would sum  the slope of year and the slope of my interaction with elevation (multiplied by my observed elevation) so `b_Year + b_Year:elevation*elevation` but how do I do that for my location term? -or how to reparameterize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of smooth-linear interaction is known as a varying coefficient model. To fit these kinds of effects in {mgcv} you use the `by` argument and pass it a continuous variable. SO I would expect something like this to do what you want:

```r
Y ~ Year + elevation + Year:elevation +
  s(lat, lon, bs = "gp") + 
  ti(lat, lon, d = 2, bs = "gp", by = Year)
```

where:

- the `s()` term accounts for the spatial variation in `Y`, and
- the `ti()` term accounts for the spatial variation in the *effect of `Year`* on `Y` (the spatially-varying linear trend)

Comment: thanks a lot! minor add: In case I have two treatments (factor) for which I want to compare the slope, my by=Year will "occupy" the by=treatment. Is there a workaround? or does this would need two separate models with slope comparison afterwards?

Comment: -would it work to set the sp in a te(lat,long,year,d=c(2,1),sp=?,by=treatment) manually somehow, i.e. so super high that this will be penalized to a linear term? but how would I set a sp for year only but not lat,long.. thanks a lot for any hint , I am a little stuck here.

Comment: An option might be to do `ti(lat, long, treatment, bs = c("tp", "re"), d = c(2,1), by = Year)` and treat the `treatment` variable as a (new style) random effect otherwise I don't think I know of what to do what you want unless you want to go to a smooth effect of `year`. Your `sp` thing would work in the sense that it would keep the marginal smooth of `Year` linear but you'd have to also figure out how to control the interaction smoothing parameter, and that model would have the same interpretation as a smoothly varying slope in the sense of the varying coefficient model

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try the ti(lat, long, treatment, bs = c("tp", "re"), d = c(2,1), by = Year) and compare results to two separate models for each treatment!